# Laravel user controller does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes

I am trying to setup my controller and route to direct to a 'view' page to show a full classified ad with more photos/info. I have it setup to just print hello for testing and i am getting a error for 'user controller does not exist'.

The href for product view is in the usercontroller so when it shows the listing on the homepage it also has the view link there. when i click the view link it takes me to the /product/view/4 but the number will change for each product so i need the route link to be able to pick that up i just dont know how to do that.

```
public function getAds(){
    $ads = DB::table('listings')->get();
    $output = '';
    if($ads->count() > 0){
        foreach($ads as $row){
            $output.= '<div class="col-md-3">
            <div style="text-align: center;">
            <img src='.strtok($row->photos, ',').' style="padding:10px !important;width:100%; height:182px;"/>
            <h3 style="margin-bottom: 5px; text-align: center; font-size: large;">'.$row->year.'</h3>
            <h3 style="margin-bottom: 5px; text-align: center; font-size: large;">'.$row->make.'</h3>
            <h3 style="margin-bottom: 5px; text-align: center; font-size: large;">'.$row->model.'</h3>                <p style="margin-bottom: 0px; text-align: center; font-size: medium;"> price: $'.$row->price.'</p>
            <p style="margin-bottom: 0px; text-align: center; font-size: medium;"> city: '.$row->city.'</p>
            <p style="margin-bottom: 0px; text-align: center; font-size: medium;"> state: '.$row->state.'</p>

            <a href='.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'product/view/'.$row->id.'>VIEW</a>
            </div>
            </div>

            ';

        }
        $output.='';
        echo $output;

    }
    else{
        $output.='<p>Not Found!</p>';
        echo $output;
    }
}
```

user controller for view

```
 public function view(){


            echo "hello";

        }



}
```

Route for view

```
Route::get('/product/view/4', 'UserController@view');
```

so now that I realized I had a spelling error in UsersController* it appears to be printing "hello". Now how can I pull the data to just show info for a specific listings 'id'? Something like this but specific to the id instead of showing all items

```
public function view(){
    $ads = DB::table('listings')->get();
    $output = '';
    if($ads->count() > 0){
        foreach($ads as $row){
            $output.= '<div class="col-md-3">
            <div style="text-align: center;">
            <img src='.strtok($row->photos, ',').' style="padding:10px !important;width:100%; height:182px;"/>
            <h3 style="margin-bottom: 5px; text-align: center; font-size: large;">'.$row->year.'</h3>
            <h3 style="margin-bottom: 5px; text-align: center; font-size: large;">'.$row->make.'</h3>
            <h3 style="margin-bottom: 5px; text-align: center; font-size: large;">'.$row->model.'</h3>                <p style="margin-bottom: 0px; text-align: center; font-size: medium;"> price: $'.$row->price.'</p>
            <p style="margin-bottom: 0px; text-align: center; font-size: medium;"> city: '.$row->city.'</p>
            <p style="margin-bottom: 0px; text-align: center; font-size: medium;"> state: '.$row->state.'</p>

            <a href='.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'product/view/'.$row->id.'>VIEW</a>
            </div>
            </div>

            ';

        }
        $output.='';
        echo $output;

    }
    else{
        $output.='<p>Not Found!</p>';
        echo $output;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you paste routes from web.php here? Also controller code

Comment: Please post the relevant code in code blocks

Comment: Please edit and post your code with your question

Answer (score 0):

Why do you render html from the controller? You have a [Blade view file](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade) to do that. With the information you give, it could be that the name of your class is misspelled, for example `UsersController` instead of `UserController`.

Comment: wow, ive been staring at this too long. THANK YOU that fixed the issue. Im still playing around with this and don't have much experience yet. I do have a blade for all my other pages. however with this page it will always be different depending on the item selected. the "id" will changing with each listing so im still unsure of how to show that.